# Generar elementos dinamicamente en una plantilla en Django

Tags: python, django

```
{%for i in cont%}
        <p>{{"module"+i}}</p>
{%endfor%}
```

Tengo este código en mi plantilla, y lo que quiero es que esta coja por cada iteración del for,un valor de un diccionario que le viene del views.py cuyas claves son module1, module2, etc...

Este es el código de mi archivo views.py en el que paso los valores a la plantilla:

```
context = {}
        for module in globals.all_modules:
            context['module' + str(cont)] = module
            cont += 1
        context['cont'] = range(1,cont)
        return render(request,'modules.html',context)
```

Con este código no muestra nada, supongo que es porque la plantilla no coge los datos que le llegan de views.py si es con comillas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La solución que he encontrado es esta.

La parte del *views.py* queda así:

```
context = {'modules' : {}}
for module in globals.all_modules:
    context['modules'][module] = "module" + str(cont)
    cont += 1
return render(request,'modules.html',context)
```

Y la parte de la plantilla así:

```
{%for module in modules%}
    <p>{{module}}</p>
{%endfor%}
```